# gcc compiler not recognizing -fno-plt option

Tags: python, gcc, quantlib

I am trying to compile QuantLib Python SWIG bindings on Amazon's EC2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI. I have managed to compile QuantLib itself successfully, however, when trying to compile anaconda python swig bindings, I am getting an error with -fno-plt option. I have upgraded the gcc compiler version to 5.4.0, originally it was 4.8

First I configure as below:

```
sudo ./configure --disable-perl --disable-ruby --disable-mzscheme --disable-guile --disable-csharp --disable-ocaml --disable-r --disable-java  PYTHON=/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Then I make as below:

```
make -C Python
```

I get the error :

```
make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.8/Python'
make  all-am

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.8/Python'
CXXFLAGS="-O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings" CC="gcc" CXX="g++" /opt/anaconda/anaconda2/bin/python setup.py build

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include -c QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.o -Wno-unused -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

make[1]: *** [.build-stamp] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.8/Python'

make: *** [all] Error 2

make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.8/Python'
```

I am very new to this and do not know if I can remove -fno-plt option when compiling and if yes, how?

Comment: It seems `-fno-plt` is supported starting GCC 6 (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to confirm this? Upgrading gcc takes a while and I just want to make sure I am upgrading to the right version.

Comment: Using Compiler Explorer - https://godbolt.org: compile any program with the `-fno-plt` option - if compilation succeeds, the flag is supported. I've verified that it is indeed not supported with GCC 5.3.1, and is supported with GCC 6.2.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to upgrade your GCC version.

The [changelog page for GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) says:

> The option -fno-plt is now fully functional.

Thus, from `GCC 6` you can use it.

Comment: Upgrading to gcc 6.1 fixed my issue. Thanks.