# Psycopg2-binary installation issue

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

While installing psycopg2 binary python package, am getting the below error

```
copg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
gcc -pthread -shared -B /data/softwares/AnacondaPackages/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/data/softwares/AnacondaPackages/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/softwares/AnacondaPackages/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wl,-O2,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I found out it is using GCC w.r.t to OS but i want GCC of conda to be used for the installation.
`pip install psycopg2-binary.tar.gz` (Offline installation)

Comment: What do you mean by "gcc of conda"? Did you install `gcc` using conda and now want that `gcc` version to be used for the compilation? A little more detail about your current setup would be helpful

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504700/gcc-compiler-not-recognizing-fno-plt-option you need to be using gcc version 6 or above. Before that the `-fno-plt` option isn't valid.

Comment: I have conda environment which has +GCC=/data/softwares/AnacondaPackages/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc

Comment: But gcc is not referring to the conda GCC instead it is looking in /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: Thanks for replies. Please tell me how to redirect the gcc path to conda gcc instead of looking in /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: By putting conda path(s) in `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`. Check with `type gcc` or `which gcc`.